# Postgres VACUUM VERBOSE information

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I am using Postgres with `psycopg2` and sometimes when I run `VACUUM VERBOSE table_name;` it gives me a line giving the `oldest xmin` and sometimes it does not. Is there a way to make sure that it **always** provides it?

Here is the output one that where it **didn't** give me the value:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.homeless_by_coc"

INFO:  scanned index "homeless_by_coc_pkey" to remove 86530 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.00 sec.

INFO:  "homeless_by_coc": removed 86530 row versions in 1280 pages
DETAIL:  CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.00 sec.

INFO:  index "homeless_by_coc_pkey" now contains 0 row versions in 239 pages
DETAIL:  86530 index row versions were removed.
236 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.00 sec.

INFO:  "homeless_by_coc": found 86530 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 1280 out of 1280 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
There were 0 unused item pointers.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU 0.00s/0.02u sec elapsed 0.03 sec.

INFO:  "homeless_by_coc": truncated 1280 to 0 pages
DETAIL:  CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.01 sec.
```

Here is one time where it **did** give it to me:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.homeless_by_coc"

INFO:  scanned index "homeless_by_coc_pkey" to remove 86530 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 0.01 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.01 s

INFO:  "homeless_by_coc": removed 86530 row versions in 1280 pages
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s

INFO:  index "homeless_by_coc_pkey" now contains 0 row versions in 239 pages
DETAIL:  86530 index row versions were removed.
236 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.

INFO:  "homeless_by_coc": found 86530 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 1280 out of 1280 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 16410
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.03 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.03 s.

INFO:  "homeless_by_coc": truncated 1280 to 0 pages
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
```

You will notice that the second time there is the following line:

```
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 16410
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be a conditional.  The extra information was added in v10 with commit [9eb344faf5](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=9eb344faf54a849898d9be012ddfa8204cfeb57c), and is always printed in that version and up for a `VACUUM VERBOSE` (it apparently is not printed for a `CLUSTER`, which does seem undesirable).

If you want consistent behavior, you need to upgrade all your database instances to the same version of PostgreSQL.